# MongoDB upsert with $push and $not

Tags: mongodb

I've recently updated to Mongodb 2.2.0 and found that the following query now no longer works.

The database is empty and I run the following:

```
db.Sessions.update({_id:"test",sessions:{$not:{$elemMatch:{type:"Web"}}}},{$push:{sessions:{type:"Web",dateAdded:new Date}}},true)
```

returns the error:

```
Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array
```

Prior to the update the following document would have been created:

```
{ "_id" : "test", "sessions" : [ { "type" : "Web", "dateAdded" : ISODate("2012-09-12T15:11:11.942Z") } ] }
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention, it's the addition of the $not that breaks in this version as the following works fine, so it's not a issue that the array/field doesn't exist.

```
db.Sessions.update({_id:"test"},{$push:{sessions:{type:"Web",dateAdded:new Date}}},true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of `$elemMatch` has changed slightly in 2.2, which is why this no longer works in combination with `$not`, which is only a [meta-operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-Metaoperator%3a%7B%7B%24not%7D%7D) for negating other operators and can not actually be used to search fields.

Instead, you can use [`$nin`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24nin) (not in) to inspect the values inside your sessions array.

For example,

```
> db.Sessions.update( { _id:"test", sessions: { "$nin": {type: "Web"} } }, {"$push":{sessions:{type:"Web",dateAdded:new Date}}},true);
> db.Sessions.findOne();
{
    "_id" : "test",
    "sessions" : [
        {
            "type" : "Web",
            "dateAdded" : ISODate("2012-09-12T16:03:18.271Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When calling the update again, it will end up pushing that object again because the $nin doesn't actually do anything. $nin is not for inspecting values inside an array.

Answer (score 2):

I filed a bug "[a query field with a $not operator should not be used to populate an upsert document](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8172)" which will be backported into 2.2.x that fixes this situation.

Comment: Verified accepted answer does not work, example from bug write up does: 
`db.test.update({_id: 1, r: {$not: {$elemMatch: {"a": 1}}}}, {$push: ...`